# Views converted to ios7 flow under navigation/bottom bars in ios6

Tags: ios

I have an app that uses stroryboards, a navigation controller and autolayout that runs fine under io6 and I would like to enable to run under both ios6 and ios7.

I have converted the app using xcode5 and it now runs fine under ios7, but when I run it under ios 6 the navigation bar and bottom bar are now transparent (they were not originally) and the view flows under them - hiding some of the controls. This persists even if I convert the ios7 app not to flow under these bars (by setting Extend Edges / Under Top Bars and Under Bottom Bars OFF).

I have worked around it by allowing ios7 to flow the view under the bars (what Apple wants us to do anyway) and then adding the following code to the viewDidLoad method of the fist view controller to force ios6 not to use transparent bars.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
}
```

This seems to be working, but I don't understand why I need to do this and I am concerned that I am missing something fundamental.

Edit: The other concern I have with this 'solution' is that the Preview in xcode5 under ios6 doesn't accurately reflect the layout as it runs under a simulator under ios 6 (I don;t have a real ios6 device handy to test it at the moment). The new preview feature in xcode5 appears to assume that the ios 6  will not flow the view under the top and bottom bars and thus squashes the controls together to fit into the available space.

Ali

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regardless of the OS version (it solved me a similar issue recently):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: OK, I can see that is a little neater. However I am still curious as to why we have to do this? Is it a bug in xcode5?

Comment: Maybe its a bug, but I'd rather say it's one of those undefined behaviours which were implemented the same way in previous iOS releases, and got suddenly changed in iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you, but there is another option to your situation: try using the __IPHONE_6_1 macro. I have an example:

```
if(__IPHONE_7_0) {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

so you could just do

```
if(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED <= __IPHONE_6_1) {
      self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
      self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = NO;
}
```

hope this helps you